# Scifi novel about two battling AI's, where one is trying to protect humanity and the second one is trying to destroy it

Tags: story-identification, novel, artificial-intelligence

The main idea was about some intelligent missile system which gone out of control. It started the war against humanity and then was defeated (or not?) by another system of that kind.

I know that Marvin Minsky recommended this book, but I was unable to find a talk/interview where he mentioned it.

This novel could be quite old, possibly published around 1985..1995.

Comment: I saw a Russian film in the 80's that had a similar concept. I don't remember enough of it to say if it has any relation at all to the book you're trying to find, but it might, and I'm just mentioning it, in case it rings a bell for someone else.

Comment: Reminds me of a side plot in "the beast of heaven" by victor kelleher. Where the two ai's by chance called a and z? And was a tribe of nomads chased by a beast involved?

Comment: Take a look at the answer for this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183676/two-computers-buried-under-the-earth/ The book and movie made from it were relatively well-known and could have attracted commentary from Minsky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my suggestion in comments above, it looks like the OP has confirmed (in a [rolled-back edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/194100/revisions)) that the book in question was *[Colossus](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?17262)* (1966) by D. F. Jones. As noted in that comment by the OP:

> For those who are interested, I found that M.Minsky talked about it in
> his ["Society of Mind" MIT course](http://www.openculture.com/2016/01/the-society-of-mind-a-free-online-course-from-marvin-minsky-pioneer-of-artificial-intelligence.html).

This story has previously been asked about and answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183676/two-computers-buried-under-the-earth/); see that question for additional details.