# American and Russian computers start talking

Tags: story-identification, books

As a Science Fiction Book Club member in the 60s I read a book about an American and Russian computer that started talking to one another and then... Can anyone share the title?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember anything else?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they trigger any other details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Possibly the same book as [Two computers buried under the earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183676/two-computers-buried-under-the-earth) ?

Comment: This was also the origin of the AI in "I have no mouth but I must scream", IIRC. That's just a short story, though and would probably be remembered for slightly different aspects of the story.

Comment: ahaha, thanks man, very funny book and film)))

Comment: @Kakturus Didn't that one have a Chinese supercomputer too?

Answer (score 27):

Sounds like the 1966 book [Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_(novel)), by D F Jones.  The Americans create a supercomputer to run the national defenses, but it discovers an equivalent Russian computer, links with it, and takes over the world.

[image]

Comment: No question.  By the way there were two sequels.  "The Fall of Colossus" and "Colossus and the Crab".  Also was filmed under the name "The Forbin Project".  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyOEwiQhzMI